# Sidekiq process to have a individual log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Currently I run the sidekiq like

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

It logs the output to `log/sidekiq.log`. But I want to have individual file for each process it runs.

For example if first process run then `sidekiq_1.log` should be created.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are running a Rails project. If you are using the new [ActiveJob](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) framework (available in Rails 4.2) you can add a `before_perform` callback and change the logger **before** a job is performed. Thus each job will log to its own file.

Example:

```ruby
class MyJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  before_enqueue do |job|
    logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new("#{self.class}-#{job.job_id}.log")
  end

  def perform(*args)
    # Do something later
  end
end
```

If you want log to different files for a couple of Jobs you can create a base class and inherit from there.

Example:

```ruby
class BaseJob < ActiveJob::Base
  before_enqueue do |job|
    logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new("#{self.class}-#{job.job_id}.log")
  end
end

class MyJob < BaseJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    logger.info 'Performing MyJob'
  end
end

class AnotherJob < BaseJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    logger.info { 'Performing AnotherJob' }
  end
end
```

If you use `Sidekiq::Worker` you can do the same thing using [Server-side middleware](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Middleware#server-side-middleware) which runs 'around' job processing:

```ruby
class Sidekiq::Middleware::Server::PerJobLogger
  def call(worker, job, queue)
    # Change logger
    Sidekiq.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new("#{job[:id]}.log")

    yield
  end
end
```

and then register the middleware with `Sidekiq`:

```ruby
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Middleware::Server::PerJobLogger
  end
end
```

Be careful tho, with the "log per job" approach you might run out of file descriptors, especially if your system processes a lot of jobs.

**NOTE**: I haven't tested the `Sidekiq::Worker` solution. Even tho the `Logger` is thread safe I haven't checked how Sidekiq uses it. But I believe you'll be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Specify a log file for each process then

```
bundle exec sidekiq --logfile log/sidekiq_1.log
bundle exec sidekiq --logfile log/sidekiq_2.log
```

Reading help helps

```
[0] % sidekiq --help
    ...
    -L, --logfile PATH               path to writable logfile
    ...
```

Comment: When i create a rails record, a sidekiq process is added up after few second it starts to execute the process. For that process i need a file. I cant run like you said.

Comment: Aren't you confusing terms here? You say "sidekiq process", but it seems that you mean "sidekiq job". Which is it?

Comment: Sidekiq 6 has dropped log file redirection and will only log to stdout.

Comment: @Ghazi struggling with the same thing. I badly need a separate file and log rotation.

Comment: `ERROR: Logfile redirection was removed in Sidekiq 6.0, Sidekiq will only log to STDOUT`