# Sidekiq is not picking up jobs from the equeued set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am running a local rails application on a VM with 64 cores and 192 GB RAM. We are running with 12 Sidekiq Processes with 10 Threads each and 40 Puma Processes.
The App Memory and CPU allocation is taken care by the docker.

The Problem we are facing is when we enqueue large number of jobs, say 1000, Sidekiq picks up 10*12 jobs and starts processing them.
Mid-execution suddenly the number of jobs running goes to 0. Moreover Sidekiq stops picking up new jobs.
All the threads in each process have the busy status but none of them processing any jobs.

This problem goes away when we reduce the number of Sidekiq Processes to 2. All the jobs process normally and Sidekiq even picks up new jobs from Enqueued Set.

What should be the correct way to debug this issue or how should I proceed further?

I tried reducing number of threads keeping the number of processes same. But that also resulted in the same issue.

Comment: Best is to monitor Sidekiq logs. I am not an expert in logs and actually my sidekiq logs appear with web logs inside `/log/development.log`. What would be great is to read about Sidekiq logging and try to have the logs in a separate file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457612/sidekiq-process-to-have-a-individual-log-file then check what is the error message of any failed Sidekiq job. As it is hard to help without any log ... (it could be a problem of database pooling, etc ..)

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting